# Is it possible to serve static content of my SPA for SEO Purpose.

Tags: seo, nginx, single-page-application, angular.js

Is it possible to serve static content of my SPA for SEO Purpose.

I have designed website in Angular4 and it is working fine. But I have used Material design and other libs which are not compatible with Angular Universal, so I cant use Angular Universal for my site.

But is it possible to serve pre generated static pages of SPA to SEO Crawler by configuring nginx reverse proxy? There is a headless chrome version available and using webdrive and python I can generated new content automatically on periodically.

Please let me know if any other alternative is possible ?

Comment: I used node prerender. https://github.com/prerender/prerender
Parsing the User-Agent in my .htaccess i expect to show robots the prerendered html and the 'real site' to the rest of users.
But i'm still struggling to be indexed. It seems is no something trivial.